# Magento - Category anchor not showing on home page

Tags: magento, anchor, categories

I've added a category to the home page using this code.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The category displays with it's products OK on the home page but I can't get the category anchor to show in the left hand side. `Is Anchor` is set to`Yes` in the Magento category configuration. I'm using Magento 1.3.2.4

Does anyone know how I can make the category anchor appear on the home page?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your Home Page's Design > Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="left"> 
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

Comment: Thank you; tho this didn't do the trick. The anchor was blank.

Comment: We're not going to use the page now, so it's not a problem anymore. Thx